# GridView Behaves Differently on phone and Emulator

Tags: android, gridview

i am new in android , when i try to run my code i just get deferent result  between  my smart phone and emulator

android version in my phone is lollipop 5
android version in emulator is lollipop 4

this photo from my phone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swjrR.png)

this photo from emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoYJV.png)

and this is my code

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        />


</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weight is not supported by GridLayout until API 21. If you want it to be supported, you might want to use GridLayout from support library v7